# image resolution in smartphones and laptop

Tags: image-processing

If I used a smartphone with high pixel per inch (ppi) value for capturing an image with certain dimensions, what happened if this image is displayed on a laptop (larger screen) with:

the same ppi value
lower ppi value
higher ppi value

Do the dimensions of the image change? or still the same?
Is interpolation required when displaying an image on a mobile phone different from the mobile phone that captured it, if both mobile phones have different ppi values?

Comment: um, what do you mean with "smartphone with high PPI for capturing"? That's not how image sensors work, at all. In fact, that's not how optics work. Not quite sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Hi! a smartphone with ppi? PPI belongs to the display not to the capturing camera...

Comment: PPI is a property of a reproduction device, e.g. a screen or a printer. You seem to be confusing a few things.

Comment: I mean that the image is captured using say, for example, the 5 megapixels camera of the smartphone, and displayed on its screen having a certain dpi value. What happens if the same 5 megapixels image is displayed on another smartphone having different screen size  and different dpi?

Comment: @Noha I don't understand the question. The screen of that smart phone has **nothing** to do with its camera and the pictures it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I mean that the image is captured using say, for example, the 5
>   megapixels camera of the smartphone, and displayed on its screen
>   having a certain dpi value. What happens if the same 5 megapixels
>   image is displayed on another smartphone having different screen size
>   and different dpi?

If you display an image (taken by whichever device, with whatever megapixel camera) on two different displays with two different DPI or PPIs, then it will **seem smaller on the high PPI** screen and larger on the low DPI screen.

This is very easy to see. Lets say the image has 2000V x 3000H pixels. And display this image on a screen with 200 PPI. Then it will take 15 inches horizontally and 10 inches vertically. On the other hand, if you display it on a second device with 100 PPI, then it will take 30 inches horizontally and 20 inches vertically, hence enlarged by 4 times. Lets conclude :

> Everything else being the same except the screen PPIs; a given image displays larger on a low PPI screen
>   and smaller on the high PPI.

Comment: in lab tops or smart phones, I can zoom the image displayed, does this mean that performing interpolation and changing the megapixel size (dimensions) of the image?

Comment: @Noha it doesn't mean that the image is changed; it says that there's a second image generated, destined for display on your device, which is scaled and potentially cropped, compared to your original image. An image is really just a rectangular table of colored pixels, and whenever you want to display, print, engrave... it anywhere, you need to take this abstract table and scale it to be either the pixel dimension (e.g. to fill your 1920x1080 phone screen) or physical dimension (e.g. to be a 13×10cm photo print) you want. That scaling *sometimes* involves interpolation.

Comment: @Marcus Müller since ppi is a specification of the screen of a smartphone, why users prefer to buy phones with large screen? If I have a phone with 8 megapixels camera and small screen size, it will be better than the one with the same 8 megapixels camera and larger screen size, right? the ppi for the small size screen will be higher, right?

Comment: @Noha because large screens are bigger.

Comment: @Marcus Müller yes, you are right. What I want to say is that having large screen is not always an advantage, since it may have low ppi.

Comment: @Marcus Müller A final comment please: since dpi and ppi are specifications for the printers or screen, what happens if they values differ between the lab top screen and the printer? For example, if the lab top screen is with 600 ppi, and the printer with 300 dpi, which value will be used for printing, 300 or 600 ?

Comment: Nothing "happens". These two devices simply exist. What happens with an image being reproduced by these devices is, I repeat myself, totally up to what your system decides to do with the image.

Answer (score 0):

Smartphones and laptops usually have GPUs.  A GPU can interpolate or resample almost any size image (in pix) to any size display (in pix, inches, etc.), larger or smaller.

Comment: since dpi and ppi are specifications for the printers or screen, what happens if they values differ between the lab top screen and the printer? For example, if the lab top screen is with 600 ppi, and the printer with 300 dpi, which value will be used for printing, 300 or 600 ?

Comment: The printer software knows nothing about the laptop screen, only the size of the source image data in storage to be printed in pix, and destination inches on paper.